# Interface declaration to handle primitive types

Tags: java, interface

I have an interface that declares `set()` method.

One implementing class operates on `byte[]` arrays, therefore it will implement `set(byte[] arr)`
Another class operates on `int[]` arrays, therefore it will implement `set(int [] arr)`.

Since `int` & `byte` are primitive types, I'm not sure how to write the interface declaration!

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
interface Name<T> {
  void set(T object);
}
```

Comment: Can T be a primitive though? E.g.

    class Something implements Name<int>
?